# Download is never complete when I'm downloading from internet

Tags: delphi, get, delphi-2010, indy, idhttp

I'm developping a download application, for that I use `Get` method of IdHTTP Indy component, now the problem I'm facing is:

When I download a file that has a small size, the download is complete, but when I download a big file it is never complete! the download is always broken. for example for a file that has a size of 100 MB, I get only 50 MB, and this is always the case. And in many times I get an exception such as:"`Access denied`", "`GMT is not a valid integer value`" ...

Why does this happen? is it relevant to the component itself? or should I add something to my code?

PS: there is no issue when I download from the local server, the download is uncomplete only when I'm downloading from internet.
Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes even major webbrowsers have trouble downloading such large files. Any number of factors can cause that. Network problems, firewall/router policies, antivirus, etc. Is there an error reported when broken? "Access denied" is hard to diagnose without context leading up to the error. But the "GMT is not a valid integer value" error has nothing to do with the size of the download, the server would have to be sending a malformed `Date` header. The HTTP protocol allows for a few different date/time formats, and `TIdHTTP` handles them all, so maybe the server is using a non-standard format.